# Brand New Dell PC and 2 Monitors 19 inch

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Just bought 2 dell 19 in monitors. Each Monitor comes with a USB 3.0 cable a-b a Display Port Cable and a VGA cable. My PC has 1 Display Port, 1 HDMI Port and 2 USB 3.0 on the Front and 2 in the back of the PC. it does not have a VGA or DVI. I wanted to ask why is there a USB 3,0 for a monitor. I need to Connect Both Monitors because its a work computer. WHich cables do i use and what is the best way to set it up. i was just going to use the Display Port  cable for 1 monitor and the HDMI for the other Monitor. Do I even need the USB 3.0 Cable ? thanks

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are using high-spec (4k/1440p/144hz) monitors you are perfectly fine with using one DisplayPort and one HDMI - you won't see any performance loss on either monitor.

The USBs are called "Pass-throughs", like a hub. It's just another option for managing cables if you'd like to plug your mouse/keyboard into them and have only one cable going from monitor to PC.

Comment: Thank you so basically the USB port on the monitor is so I can hook up the mouse and keyboard

Comment: You can plug any USB device into it. You'll have to run the USB A>B cable from your PC to the monitor for it to work, and the other port will essentially become an extension. Fun note: be careful about putting a thumb drive in and forgetting about it as it can cause boot priority issues that can be difficult to diagnose.

Answer (score 2):

You will be fine with 1. DisplayPort and 2. HDMI, that are the two best options.

Sell the VGA and USB cables to your friends or keep them for a rainy day.